# How to split object into list of objects by list property C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, split

I have an object which contains a property of type of `List` of another objects:

```
public class MyObject {
    public List<AnotherObject> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

`MyProperty` has several items.

I want to split `MyObject` into `List<MyObject>` by `MyProperty` items so that each MyObject contains `MyProperty` with only one `AnotherObject` as `List<AnotherObject>`.

How to do it?

Comment: So you want to make copies of your `MyObject` instances? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to implement the [IClonable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface into your `MyObject` class. This way you can make independent copies of the base object. 
All other properties in the class `MyObject` will keep their values!

```
public class MyObject :ICloneable
{
    public List<AnotherObject> MyProperty { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then iterate over the `List<AnotherObject> MyProperty` create a copy and overwrite the List object in the copy:

Here is a working example:

```
MyObject mobj = new MyObject();
mobj.MyProperty = new List<UserQuery.AnotherObject>();
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());
mobj.MyProperty.Add(new AnotherObject());


List<MyObject> splitList = new List<MyObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < mobj.MyProperty.Count; i++) 
{   
    // get the reference to the object from the list
    AnotherObject temp = mobj.MyProperty[i];
    // make a deep copy of the base object
    MyObject clone = mobj.Clone() as MyObject;
    // overwrite the internal list and put the reference to the item into the list
    clone.MyProperty = new List<AnotherObject> {temp};
    // add the copied object to the split list
    splitList.Add(clone);
}
```

Note that the `AnotherObject` items are just references! so changing the values in the list of the base object will change the values in the single list items of the copies!

Comment: I did not mention that MyObject had other properties as well so it's not only MyProperty that needs splitting but others retaining. So I find IClonable and cloning particularly useful for this reason. Thank you.

Comment: @nickornotto I assumed that it would go in this direction. I have seldomly seen an class with only 1 property :). You are very welcome. Would you mind telling me in which scenario you are operating so that you need to split this object into a list? I am very curious, because I cannot deduce on my own such a scenario where it would be necessary

Comment: I am splitting a booking items into separate MyObject to send each item separately by email but have to keep the parent object data

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) to get an [`IEnumerable<MyObject>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7):

```
var splits = existing.MyProperty.Select(ao => new MyObject {MyProperty = new List<AnotherObject> {ao}});
```

If you specifically need a [`List<MyObject>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7):

```
var asList = splits.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var query = from p in obj.MyProperty
            select new MyObject() { MyProperty = new List<AnotherObject>() { p } };
```